# How to add timestamp and date to the log file that is created using RotatingFilehandler

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-logging

I need to get output log files with current date and time. In my code 5 log files will be created. Each log file name should contain the current date and time. I don't want to use "TimedRotatingFileHandler" in my code. But using "RotatingFileHandler", I don't know how to add time and date in the filename. Here is what I tried so far:

```
import time
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from datetime import datetime
from logging import FileHandler
from time import strftime
now =datetime.now()
Filename= now.strftime('app_%H_%M_%d_%m_%Y.log')


log_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s](%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')

logFile = 'D:/Tasks/1212/app'+ Filename

my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(logFile, mode='a', maxBytes=5*1024, 
                             backupCount=5, encoding=None, delay=0)

my_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
my_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app_log = logging.getLogger('root')
app_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app_log.addHandler(my_handler)

while True:
   app_log.info("data")
   time.sleep(1)
logging.shutdown
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove spelling and grammar mistakes to make it easier for people to understand your problem. Could you please make sure that I did not distort the meaning and that the question is still what you wanted to ask? Also you might want to consider adding your reasoning for using `RotatingFileHandler` and not using `RimedRotatingFileHandler`. That will give people trying to answer your question a better idea about possible constraints. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, it still comes up as a top result when searching Google for things like "Python rotate log with timestamp".  I'm having the same issue because I want to have a set number of log files that are rolled over based on file size, and I want to have a timestamp in each file name.  I'm on a system with a limited amount of disk space, so staying within space constraints is important, but there could also be long periods of time where there is no activity at all, and I do not want older files to be removed and replaced with empty logs just because they're old.

Short answer: you cannot do this with `RotatingFileHandler`.  It is only capable of taking a static name and appending a number to it, then renaming old files to remove the oldest one and ensure that the newest one is always the same as the base name.

The solution to this problem is to write your own log handler.  Here's a `RotatingTimestampLogHandler` I wrote that will use file size as a trigger to roll over log files and insert the creation time in the log file's name.  If your log file rolls over fast enough that a new file would be created with the same timestamp as a previous one, it will make a new file with a number appended to it.

```py
import io
from logging.handlers import BaseRotatingHandler
import os


class RotatingTimestampLogHandler(BaseRotatingHandler):
    def __init__(self, prefix, suffix='', mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0,
                 time_format='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%f', encoding=None, delay=False, errors=None):
        """
        Returns a new instance of the RotatingTimestampLogHandler class.  This will maintain a set of log
        files that are rotated when the log file's size exceeds a certain amount, similar to RotatingFileHandler,
        except that it can place a timestamp on the log file's name at the time the file is created.  Numbers
        will only be appending to log files when multiple logs are created at the same timestamp.

        :param prefix: String to put at the beginning of the file name.
        :param suffix: String to put at the end of the file name.
        :param mode: Same as FileHandler.
        :param maxBytes: Maximum number of bytes in a file; a rollover will happen when this is exceeded.
        :param backupCount: Maximum number of log files to maintain; older ones will be removed.
        :param time_format: Python strftime formatting string that will be inserted between the prefix and suffix.
        :param encoding: Same as FileHandler.
        :param delay: Same as FileHandler.
        :param errors: Same as FileHandler.
        """
        if maxBytes > 0:
            mode = 'a'
        if 'b' not in mode:
            encoding = io.text_encoding(encoding)
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.time_format = time_format
        self.fileList = []
        self.update_filename()
        self.fileList.append(self.baseFilename)
        BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, self.baseFilename, mode, encoding=encoding, delay=delay, errors=errors)
        self.maxBytes = maxBytes
        self.backupCount = backupCount

    def update_filename(self):
        new_filename = '{}{}{}'.format(self.prefix, datetime.now().strftime(self.time_format), self.suffix)

        if len(self.fileList) > 0 and self.fileList[-1].startswith(new_filename):
            if len(self.fileList[-1]) == len(new_filename):
                number = 1
            else:
                number = int(self.fileList[-1][len(new_filename)+1:]) + 1
            new_filename = '{}.{}'.format(new_filename, number)

        self.baseFilename = new_filename

    def doRollover(self):
        """
        Do a rollover, as described in __init__().
        """
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        if 0 < self.backupCount:
            while len(self.fileList) >= self.backupCount:
                old_file = self.fileList.pop(0)
                if os.path.exists(old_file):
                    os.remove(old_file)
        self.update_filename()
        self.fileList.append(self.baseFilename)
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()

    def shouldRollover(self, record):
        """
        Determine if rollover should occur.

        Basically, see if the supplied record would cause the file to exceed
        the size limit we have.
        """
        # See bpo-45401: Never rollover anything other than regular files
        if os.path.exists(self.baseFilename) and not os.path.isfile(self.baseFilename):
            return False
        if self.stream is None:                 # delay was set...
            self.stream = self._open()
        if self.maxBytes > 0:                   # are we rolling over?
            msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
            self.stream.seek(0, 2)  # due to non-posix-compliant Windows feature
            if self.stream.tell() + len(msg) >= self.maxBytes:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

for those of you unsatisfied with `*this cannot be done*`, here's a solution that works well and says `*of course it can be done!*`.  i also threw in some other stuff that makes log life sweet aaaand i added compression to boot so you don't have to worry about space:

```py
import datetime,logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import gzip,shutil

logpath = '/var/log/biggusLoggus/biggusLoggus.log'

def namer(name):
    tempName = name.split('.')
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%b%d_%H%M%S')
    tempName.insert(1, timestamp)[:-2]  #<-- this clips the numbering
    name = '_'.join(tempName)
    return name + '.gz'

def rotator(source, dest):
    with open(source, 'rb') as f_in:
        with gzip.open(dest, 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
    os.remove(source)

rotatingLogHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logPath, maxBytes=10*1024*1024, backupCount=10)
rotatingLogHandler.rotator = rotator
rotatingLogHandler.namer = namer


logFormat = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d [%(levelname)8s] %(lineno)4d: ·%(funcName)s· %(message)s','%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')
rotatingLogHandler.setFormatter(logFormat)
rotatingLogHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)  #<-- will only log this level and up

logg = logging.getLogger('biggusLoggus')
# ↓ this is the OVERALL base level of logging CAPABILITY. each handler has it's own level
logg.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  
logg.addHandler(rotatingLogHandler)

#  now log some stuff
logg.info(f'kablam!  i am logging, baby, yeah!')
```

tune as you see fit.  works like a charm

Answer (score -1):

When `RotatingFileHandler` is used, the name of log file is fixed at beginning, and when in rotating the new log file is always based on the filename at beginning.

Just refer to doc of it:

*For example, with a backup count of 5 and a **base file name** of "app.log", you would get "app.log", "app.log.1", "app.log.2", ... through to "app.log.5". **The file being written to is always "app.log"** - when it gets filled up, it is closed and renamed to "app.log.1", and if files app.log.1", "app.log.2" etc. exist, then they are renamed to "app.log.2", "app.log.3" etc.*

Comment: The question is asking how he can add the time/datestamp to the filename using a RotatingFileHandler